# Android: ACTION_SEND intent to Facebook application

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

When I send ACTION_SEND intent to Facebook application with EXTRA_STREAM

> "content://com.mycompany.myapplication/image.jpg" and mime type "image/jpeg" Facebook application cannot add image to post.

But other applications like google+, twitter, dropbox and so on accept it.
What do I make wrong?

Comment: If you try sharing an image via some other app, like the Gallery, does it work with Facebook? If not, then the problem is with Facebook, not your code, in all likelihood.

Comment: Problem is that applications like dropbox and many other share files like files - "file://dropbox/image.jpg". But I need to use content provider to share files with other applications. Question is why Facebook doesn't understand content provider uri.

Comment: The reason I suggested Gallery is that, AFAIK, it will use `content://` `Uri` values.

Comment: Another problem - I store my files with SHA1 name w/o extension. And when I try to share it like "file://.../SHA1" and valid mime type Facebook doesn't recognize it as valid image again.

Comment: @CommonsWare On my Galaxy S4 gallery cannot share image to Facebook with same error.

Comment: The problem is with Facebook, presumably. They must assume that incoming `Uri` values are `file://`, instead of using a `ContentResolver` to handle multiple possible `Uri` structures. Are you seeing a specific error in LogCat from Facebook?